# No provider for LocationStrategy error message in Angular2 Dart

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I'm getting this error in my main component of a small Angular2 application. Here's my code at the moment:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: const[ClientService, Location])
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  final ClientService _clientService;

  Client client;
  final Location _location;

  AppComponent(this._clientService, this._location);

  @override
  ngOnInit() async {
    var components = _location.path().split('/').skip(1).toList();
    if (components.isEmpty) return;
    if (components.first=="client" && components.length==2) {
      client = await _clientService.getById(components.skip(1).first);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to get the current browser location in angular2? Maybe using window.location would be easier.

Comment: How does `bootstrap(...)` look like?

Comment: it's like this: "bootstrap(AppComponent);".

Answer (score 2):

Add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to `bootstrap(...)` and remove `Location` from providers in `AppComponent`

```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
```

This probably also fixes the issue in your other question with `RouteParams`